# SVG Square cropped by text around it

Tags: svg, text, square

Is there a way to make a svg square which will be behind of a text and that text to crop around it the square like in the following picture?

[image]

Please note that there will be a background image behind and not a solid color.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You just need to use the text as a mask.  For the version of the text in the mask, we give it a thick stroke so that it masks out more of the rectangle around it.

I've wrapped the SVG in a brown `<div>` so that you can see that this works with any background.

```css
div {
  background-color: sandybrown;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <svg width="300" height="100">
    <defs>
      <g id="text" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle">
        <text x="150" y="48">This text will vertically</text>
        <text x="150" y="70">crop this square</text>
      </g>

      <mask id="textmask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="0" y="0" width="300" height="100">
        <rect width="300" height="100" fill="white"/>
        <use xlink:href="#text" stroke="black" stroke-width="10"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
  
    <rect x="101" y="1" width="98" height="98"
          fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          mask="url(#textmask)"/>

    <use xlink:href="#text"/>
    
  </svg>
  
</div>
```